# Three js XRMediaBinding ( webXR ) - how to add a custom fragment shader on an equirectLayer?

Tags: three.js, glsl, webxr

In ThreeJS, when displaying a 360 degree equirectangular video on an equirectLayer, does anyone know how to pass a custom fragment shader to the layer, to do some postprocessing to the video ?

Answer (score 0):

That is impossible, purpose of layer is ready-to-use.
You need to do pre-processing for video before passing it into xr layer